# How to draw inverse path in xamarin android

Tags: android, path, xamarin.android

I have drawn two arcs using path like below:

```
  path.ArcTo(rc, (float)startangle1, (float)((angle1 - startangle1)));
  path.ArcTo(innerrc, (float)(angle), (float)((startangle - angle))); 
  path.Close();
  canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```

I can see two arcs rendering based on the angle value. But at some condition the arcs rendering inversely. I need to restrict the inverse rendering behavior.

Is there any option for path to specify clockwise or anti-clockwise or any alternate solution for this when using path.

Comment: define the term `inverse path`

Comment: can u share me the Syntax please

Comment: syntax? what syntax? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: i just want to draw the arcs with inverse angle and is there any option to draw path anti clockwise ??

Comment: if you want inverse angle just use negative `sweepAngle`